# Get Botbuilder Signin button cancel response

Tags: typescript, azure, botframework, microsoft-teams

Crowd,

I'm struggling on an issue reacting to denied consent in Teams SSO.

My solution looks like this:

1. I have a webserver doing some conversational logic written in typescript reachable via ngrok
2. I have an Azure bot
3. I have an Azure AD bot registration

When requesting permissions I'm creating an oauthcard that is sent as an attachment like this:

```
await CardFactory.oauthCard(
    myConnectionName,
    "Title",
    "text",
    signInLink,
    {
        id: this.accessToken,
        uri: `api://botid-${myAppId}`
    }
);
```

This works fine, the user receives a small prompt "We need to ask for additional permissions. You should only need to do this once for MyApplication" with two buttons "Cancel" and "Continue".

Continue works fine, the webserver receives a response, can get the Token for GraphAPI and use all cool features, but what about the cancel button?

Unfortunately I receive exactly 0 feedback if the user clicks "Cancel". Do you know if there's a way to get a confirmation when the user clicks cancel?

I already added an adapter and check each activity using adapter.processActivity() but there's no activity or web request coming in for cancelations.

Any idea how to handle this? Do I need to somehow add a different link for the cancel button? The attachment I'm sending looks like this:

```
{
        "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.oauth",
        "content":{
           "buttons":[
              {
                 "type":"signin",
                 "title":"Title",
                 "value":"https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=mySignInId"
              }
           ],
           "connectionName":"myConnection",
           "tokenExchangeResource":{
              "id":"myAccessToken",
              "uri":"api://botid-myAppId"
           },
           "text":"text"
        }
     }
```

Any ideas how to receive a response or fetch this event?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

[image: My Permission request screen]

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the screen you are getting having cancel and continue button?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT attached it :)

Comment: Could you please share any public sample or doc you are following? So that we can repro it at our end?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT that's exactly the problem. There is exactly 0 documentation to find how to handle decline consent documents. For setting up my SSO I followed this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-sso/7-exercise-bots-sso, I also looked at the Javascript_Node examples 18 and 46 in https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples and spent countless hours browsing the internet

Comment: We have tested and it doesn't invoke any activity. Confirming internally if it is by design.

Comment: Can you confirm what is the use case for Cancel button tracking?

Comment: I'm working at a provider for conversational AI(Chatbot software). We offer a modular solution our customers can use to build conversational logic with a lot of different endpoints and it was my task to modify our Teams endpoint to get sure customers can use SSO with consent approval. Right now we can trigger the consent dialog but we don't know if the user hasn't clicked anything or declined it so we can't react to his action and apply any kind of upcoming logic depending on his choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected to be handled by Teams client, If we pass this control to the Bot, the requests would get into a loop and we want to avoid that.
For example, user interacts with Bot -> client shows consent pop up -> User cancels -> Bot again initializes Auth request -> client again shows pop up -> `...`

So, this is by design. Teams client will show the consent pop up when user tries to interact with the Bot again.